# How can I use alternate shape templates in different zones on the same page?

Tags: orchardcms

I'm trying to create a theme in orchard. I have a main content zone and a sidebar zone which is on the right of my main content area (2 column layout). The main content area displays a list of blog posts (including tags, etc. Standard Orchard behaviour).

In the sidebar I would like to display the recent blog post widgets. However, the standard widget renders tags, published date etc. I do not want to display this information in the sidebar zone.

The placement file does not seem to be the right place to configure this as I can't specifically target the Parts_Tags_ShowTags shape in the sidebar zone. Neither does it seem to be possible to create a new template like Tags.ShowTags-Sidebar.cshtml

Any suggestions on how to modify/hide a shape in one zone on a page but not the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use an alternate (shape tracing can help with that) or take this over entirely (see this post for details: http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2011/03/27/taking-over-list-rendering-in-orchard.aspx)

Comment: Hi Bertrand, I was initially thinking of shape alternatives but the problem is that I also have a blog list on the same page. So whatever change I make to the blogpost summary alternate template would also show up in the blogpost list, no?

Comment: no, that's the point of alternates: if you choose or create the right one, you can target changes exactly to what you want.

Comment: The problem I had was exactly the one described in the link you posted, only that I wanted to change the RecentPost widget without affecting the BlogPost list. Due to the fact that you can't target specific zones in the placement.info file I couldn't hide the meta information in my sidebar. I was just looking at the wrong level, I should have targeted the RecentPosts template rather than the ones below it. That said it would be great to be able to target zones in the placement.info file.